# Issue with constraint layout not showing unless I add absolute dimension

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have this layout and am trying to switch on a corresponding LL based on a position. However the first Linear Layout will only show up and be drawn if I give the text view inside an absolute dimension such as 200dp for the width, I have tried 0dp with constraints as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/draft_rider_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="#000000"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="lost"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/section"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fake"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:text="Andrea Dovizioso's"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rider_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:text="Andrea Dovizioso's"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is rendered from a recycler view that is on my fragment which is placed like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".roster.RosterFragment">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/player_rider_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/baseline_edit_white_24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

And here is my adapter :

```
class PlayerRidersAdapter :  RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerRidersAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

var riderList = ArrayList<Rider>()

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rider_item_layout, null, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return riderList.count() + 2
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when(position) {
        0 -> showHeader(holder)
        3 -> showSection(holder)
        else -> showRow(holder)
    }
}

fun showHeader(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.headerContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.sectionContainer.visibility = View.GONE
    holder.rowContainer.visibility = View.GONE
}

fun showRow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.headerContainer.visibility = View.GONE
    holder.sectionContainer.visibility = View.GONE
    holder.rowContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    //holder.name.text = rider.name
}

fun showSection(holder: ViewHolder) {
    holder.headerContainer.visibility = View.GONE
    holder.sectionContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    holder.rowContainer.visibility = View.GONE
}

fun addRiders(riders : ArrayList<Rider>){
    riderList.addAll(riders)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var headerContainer = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.header)
    var sectionContainer = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.section)
    var rowContainer = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.row)
    var name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.rider_name)
}
}
```

Comment: A couple things come to mind. (1) ConstraintLayout doesn't support `match_parent`; you have to use `0dp` with both sides constrained to the parent. (2) What does your implementation of `onCreateViewHolder()` look like?

Comment: IMO you could optimize your layout by having just 3 `TextView` inside the `ConstraintLayout`. what do you mean by first Linear Layout? are you talking about `header`?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, specify the following in *onCreateViewHolder()*:

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rider_item_layout, parent, false)
```

Specifying the *root* argument will let the inflated layout be sized properly. This is most likely your problem.

However, *match_parent* sometimes has strange behavior when used in *ConstraintLayout*, so use `0dp` instead and remember to constrain the effected sides. It would be nice for *ConstraintLayout* to either handle this case, report it as an error or, at least, support a Lint check.

An aside: The constraints on the *TextViews* that are held within a *LinearLayout* have no effect. Constraints only apply to *direct* children of *ConstraintLayout*.